# Storyboard custom sender for button press

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard, sender

I was wondering if it was possible to set a different UIView as the "sender" object for a button press in XCode.

To be clear, when I press a button, my IBAction is called but I would like the "sender" object that is passed to that action to be another UIView in the same storyboard rather than the button itself.

Is this possible? It would allow me to simplify some code and let the button press change the appearance of a different UI element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as the sender should be either `Any` or `UIButton` which reference the linked button ,but you can give that view a tag and access it like this in the `IBAction` method

```
let innerView = self.view.viewWithTag(12)
```